# Convert NSDate to another format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have an NSDate that logs to console (on my machine with my settings) like this:

2015-12-30 18:10:27 +0000

How would I convert it to a string that I can store on a remote server like this?

2015-12-30 18:10:27

Since the server must serve multiple clients, it is important that the dates on it always be in a consistent format.

My understanding is that NSFormatter uses local settings that vary by client so I cannot rely on it to always provide the same string format for saving on a server so therefore I am at a loss:

Here is code I have so far:

```
    NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
    NSLog(@"date is:%@",date); //logs as above => 2015-12-30 18:10:27 +0000
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *datestring = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"datestring%@",datestring); //logs => 2015-12-30T13:10:27.000Z
```

This is not quite what I want and I'm also not confident this will always create the same format on different handhelds for saving on a server.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNIX timestamp:

```
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
```

Or you can set custom date format of your NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
NSString *datestring = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: If I use unix time stamp, doesn't the time turn into GMT and therefore lose local time for user?  If I use date formatter, does the custom date format trump any other settings the user might have so I can be sure to always get the same thing on the server end?

Comment: UNIX timestamp is independent of time zone. All users in all timezones have the same timestamp at the same time.

Comment: Also if you want to use date formatter you can set the same custom timezone for all users: `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];`